# Using chat application into sharepoint site using silverlight

Tags: .net, silverlight, c#-4.0, sharepoint

In my project that is requirement of chat application. Leader told me to do that using the
Silverlight. Please give me path for it.ASAP.

Comment: I think, you should ask your LEADER to sit with you & design solution together, then google something like this "silverlight webpart in sharepoint 2013". Sharepoint SDK, Samples, Silverlight Samples (VS Project Templates comes with basic implementation). Because these two are platforms on its own. best luck

Comment: is there any way to implement chat services into the sharepoint site?

Comment: please guide me. :) .. it is necessary now.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion what he wants to tell you is as follows. You can create your chat-application using silverlight. After you've got a working solution, you can display it inside your SharePoint using Silverlight-Webpart. This webpart is able to "embed" silverlight-application directly into SharePoint without much effort.

Comment: oohk.. that is so helping sir.. sir can you tell me how to start building it.. please give me some steps to do so.. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: If you have to start from the scratch, have a lookt at:[Walkthrough: Creating Your First Silverlight Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838218%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or please search the web for "Silverlight Chat", if you can find already working solutions.

Comment: it will work for all users who are online in sharepoint site.?? does it having that type of configuration?? if it is not silverlight then can you tell me that how to go for the chat facility in to sharepoint .. any other ways?

Comment: If you are looking for a pretty simple solution, please have a look at this [Chat in SharePoint - The Easy Way No Code](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/Chat-in-SharePoint-The-Easy-Way-No-Code.aspx)

Comment: i dont need this.. i want pure chat application.. :)

Comment: Feel free to implement or search for it ;)